# Problemas al distribuir aplicación de Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyinstaller

Soy un desarrollador novato en python y luego de unas semanas pude crear una aplicación para procesar datos UV-Vis para mi proyecto de investigación. Uso las librerías conocidas numpy, matplotlib y algunas funciones de scipy. He podido armar mi ejecutable con pyinstaller, y la app funciona bien en mi computadora.

El problema ocurre cuando he intentado distribuir mi aplicación. Lo primero que hice fue transferir los archivos de la carpeta dist por usb a otra computadora de mi casa y sí funcionó pude realizar varias cosas en mi aplicación; sin embargo, probé distribuirla a algunas personas por Google Drive y la aplicación se abría, pero al ejecutar alguna operación que podría demorar alrededor de 10 segundos la aplicación se cerraba. ¿Alguien sabe qué podría estar pasando?

También desarrollé un instalador con "INO", pero en algunas computadoras Windows Defender protegía la instalación. ¿Tienen alguna recomendación para poder distribuir mi aplicación? Pesa alrededor de 700 MB.

Comment: Opinión: pyinstaller con la opción onedir, y fijate de desactivarle la compresión upx. Se supone que que la carpeta que te genera es portable en Windos únicamente, ten en  cuenta, si tu ditribución es de 64 bits que no va a funcionar en 32 bits.

Comment: A veces Google Drive me detectaba partes del ejecutable pyinstaller como virus, a lo mejor eso te está ocurriendo? (no te notifica a ti, el dueño). Adicionalmente tal vez las otras computadoras se esten quedando sin RAM?

Comment: Luego de seguir la recomendación de @PatricioMoracho crea una cuenta en github (si no tienes una - es gratuito), sube el proyecto tal como lo tienen en tu pc y compártelo desde allí. No uses GoogleDrive ni trates de anexarlo a correos (muchos programas paranoides lo tomarán como virus)

Comment: Puede que tu ejecutable esté siendo bloqueado al ser detectado como virus. Debes asegurarte de que tienes instalado *Python x86* si tu máquina es x86, o *Python x64* en equipos x64. Comprueba si tu aplicación es detectada en https://www.virustotal.com. Te recomiendo que reinstales *pyinstaller* creando el *bootloader* tú mismo: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html (al hacer esto mis ejecutables dejaron de ser detectados en la mayoría de antivirus de *virustotal*). Como alternativa a *INO* a mi me gusta [InstallForge](https://installforge.net), que es mas fácil.

Comment: Gracias a todos, he tomado la sugerencia de PatricioMoracho y quevedo. Al parecer, el problema era que mi aplicación fue construida en Windows 10 Pro y no en Home, por eso falló en las computadoras con dicho sistema operativo. Aún no he probado la última sugerencia porque las pruebas las haremos luego. Nuevamente, gracias a todos!